# How to Get C# with WPF/XAML Animation Running Smoothly with Other Code Running Concurrently

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, animation

I have looked in Stackoverflow and have not seen anything with regard to this yet.

Currently, I am using an animation to get a groupbox to flash while an operation is occurring (i.e. other work). Unfortunately, the flashing is not smooth due to the other operations/work being run. I have tried by interspersing ThreadHelper.DoEvents() which helps but is not nearly enough. Is there a way to cause the animation updating to occur smoothly (i.e. flashing is not consistent) without putting all the other operations on their own thread (believed to be too complex due to interaction with UI)? Preferred would be to put the updating of the groupbox animation in its own thread (or something like this or ??)?

The animation is as follows:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="FlashingGroupBoxForTest" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="StartTest">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Triggers are used to start and stop the animation

```
        <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PerformingFocusTest, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource FlashingGroupBoxForTest}"     
                                            ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
    </ei:DataTrigger>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PerformingFocusTest, Mode=OneWay}" Value="False">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource FlashingGroupBoxForTest}"     
                                            ControlStoryboardOption="Stop"/>
    </ei:DataTrigger>
```

Thanks for looking and any help is appreciated.

Best,

Buck

Comment: Is the backgroujd task running in a different thread? If not, you will probably never get around this problem completelly, because your worker interruprs the animation.

Comment: put the heavy work in a background thread. Your code should have no interaction at all with the UI except `NotifyPropertyChanged()` being raised in the UI thread. You need to create a proper ViewModel and do your stuff there, learn MVVM. WPF does not support developers with a winforms mentality. `DoEvents()` is the worst idea ever.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have a couple other background tasks going but in general they are just a minor percentage of the application. I have had difficulty in the past getting the background threads propagating up their changes to the UI (interesting point to potentially solve but too costly to redesign). Hmm, interesting your comment about the workers always interrupting the animation. Can't the animation be given enough priority directly/indirectly to solve it? Just double-checking since intuitively it seems like a solution (besides redesign) should be present (but maybe wrong). Tx again